# How to make a property with known and fixed values for a user-defined button?

Tags: c#, winforms, methods, properties

I have a user-defined button, and it may have a `Style` property which I choose in `properties` window a value for it and depending on that value its Image and style will change.

**How can I make this property to have some predefined and fixed values in a drop down list in `properties` window? and selecting a value causes running a method**

---

**-details:**

this button may gets specified appearance such *pause* and *play* styles. so I made a class for styles:

```
// style of the button; pause, play, reset, etc
public abstract class ButtonStyle
{
    public abstract Image GetImage();
}
// inherited classes of class ButtonStyle
public class PauseButtonStyle : ButtonStyle
{
    public override Image GetImage()
    {
        return CustomButtonLibrary.Properties.Resources.PauseButton;
    }
}
public class PlayButtonStyle : ButtonStyle
{
    public override Image GetImage()
    {
        return CustomButtonLibrary.Properties.Resources.PlayButton;
    }
}
```

And there is a method in the button for setting the specified style (pause,play,...):

```
public void SetStyle(ButtonStyle style)
{
    button1.Image = style.GetImage();                       
}
```

Now how can I have a property for this custom button in `properties` window that this property has some default values like `pause`, `play`,etc **and selecting it causes changing the button's style (with running SetStyle method)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would make an enum and expose that as the `Style` property. Then, have a internal dictionary that keys off the enum value to choose the appropriate `ButtonStyle` object to pass to your `SetStyle` method.

Comment: I was thinking for this and the only thing that avoid me was not using a method inside a property. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think all you need to do is inherit the `Button` class and add your Enum:

```
public class ButtonEx : Button
{
  public enum ButtonStateStyles
  {
    None,
    Pause,
    Play,
  }

  private ButtonStateStyles _ButtonStateStyle = ButtonStateStyles.None;

  public ButtonStateStyles ButtonStateStyle
  {
    get { return _ButtonStateStyle; }
    set
    {
      _ButtonStateStyle = value;

      switch (_ButtonStateStyle)
      {
        case ButtonStateStyles.Pause:
          {
            base.Image = new PauseButtonStyle().GetImage();
            break;
          }
        case ButtonStateStyles.Play:
          {
            base.Image = new PlayButtonStyle().GetImage();
            break;
          }
        default:
          {
            base.Image = null;
            break;
          }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but is calling a method inside a property a good work?

Comment: @Mouliyan Depends on the method, I suppose.  Your method is just changing other properties, so it's ok.  My machine didn't mind.